# How can I import SVG in konvajs and convert each layer of SVG as a separate layer in konvajs?

Tags: angular, svg, converters, konva

I am developing a web application by angular and Konvajs. I have a problem as follows.

I imported SVG file into konvajs but I want to be able to edit each layer of SVG file separately in konvajs, or convert SVG file content to a format (like json) to load into konvajs.

Is there a perfect SVG-to-Konva convertor ?